# How to get @Html.RadioButtonFor selected value to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm beginner for ASP.NET MVC. I have tried creating a strongly typed view and got stuck with an issue of getting the selected Radio button value to the controller.

Here is my Model,

```
public class FacilityBookingCharges
{
    public long FacilityBookingChargesID { get; set; }

    public bool PricingType { get; set; }

    public Pricingperhour Pricingperhour { get; set; }

    public Pricingpersession Pricingpersession { get; set; }

    public Pricingperday Pricingperday { get; set; }
}
```

Here I declared PricingType as boolean which I'll use for my Radiobutton binding.

Below is how I bind the radio button in my view

```
@model Facility.Models.FacilityBookingCharges

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PricingType,"Pricingperhour", new { @id="Pricingperhour",@checked = "checked" })

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PricingType,"Pricingpersession", new { @id="Pricingpersession" })

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PricingType,"Pricingperday", new { @id="Pricingperday" })
```

My understanding:

1. User must select either one of the above 3 Radio buttons. So, I have bind those Radio buttons with a "single" boolean property "PricingType", according to my understanding this enables the Radio button grouping(feel free to correct me if i'm wrong).
2. While binding the Radio button, my 2nd param denotes the value getting bind with the respective radio button. It will looks like below once it renderes

   <'input id="Pricingperhour" type="radio" value="Pricingperhour"'>

My Question:

Now I want to get the value of Radio button which is selected by the User.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what your asking. You binding the radio buttons to a `boolean` property which has only 2 possible values, `true` or `false`. But you give then values `Pricingperhour`, `Pricingpersession` and `Pricingperday` which cant be bound to a `bool` and the value of `PricingType` will always be `false` when you post. Change your property to `string PricingType`

Comment: Is it not necessary to bind Radiobutton  with boolean ?

Comment: As I noted its very unclear what your wanting to do here. With your current view, then your property needs to be `public string PricingType { get; set; }` and when you submit, the value of `PricingType` will be either `"Pricingperhour"`, `"Pricingpersession"` or `"Pricingperday"`. Alternatively if you want to bind to a `bool`, then you need 2 radio buttons -`@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PricingType, "True")` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PricingType, "False")`. Either way your model currently makes no sense so suggest you explain what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, but it still makes not sense. Clearly you do not understand what a radio button is for. It is used to select one from many options. In you case you are generating 3 options and the values of those options are `Pricingperhour`, `Pricingpersession` and `Pricingperday` which are `string` - therefor your property needs to be `public string PricingType { get; set; }` (NOT a `bool`). But then you have 3 other properties which are typeof `Pricingperhour` etc so it just makes no sense. Try and explain what your trying to do!

Comment: Based on the user's selection I need to load the partial view of type Pricingperhour, Pricingpersession or Pricingperday. Just ignore that code now. It's not related to my question. My question is all about how to get the selected radio value back to the controller. You answered saying creating the property of type "String" instead of boolean will resolve this. Let me try that. Thanks.